# Netty Server/Client Connection established but client closes unexpected with no error

Tags: java, netty

First of all thank you for spending your time reading this.

I am currently stuck with a quite weird bug. I am a bit familiar with java but new to Netty. I am writing a Chat Program similar to the SecureChat in the examples.

My problem is: I am able to start the Server. The server binds to the correct address with no errors. But when I start the client, it connects to the server waits a couple of seconds and terminates, with no console output directing the type of the error. 
The channels seem to be established and active, at least the corresponding methods are called.  The server should be sending a greetings packet when the Channel/Connection is active. 
This greetings packet is not being received by the client. Or at least it seems like it's not.

ChatServer.java:

```
package main;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassResolvers;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectEncoder;

public class ChatServer {

private final int port;

public ChatServer(int port){
    this.port = port;
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try{
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception     {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(
                    new ObjectEncoder(),
                    new     ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                    new ChatServerHandler());   
            }
        });
        b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port;
    if (args.length > 0){
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } else {
        port = 3000;
    }
    new ChatServer(port).run();
}

}
```

ChatServerHandler.java:

```
package main;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter;
import net.Packet;
import net.server.ChannelIntercommunicationHandler;
import net.server.PacketGreetings;

public class ChatServerHandler extends ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<Packet>{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChatServerHandler.class.getName());

@Override
public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
    ctx.write(new PacketGreetings("Hello! Welcome in Chat. Please log in"));
    ChannelIntercommunicationHandler.addChannel(ctx.channel());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sent greetings packet to User with ChannelID: "+ctx.channel().id());
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet request) throws Exception {
    ChannelIntercommunicationHandler.packetReceived(ctx.channel(), request);
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Error, Exiting.");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unexpected exception from downstream.", cause);
    ChannelIntercommunicationHandler.cleanupChannel(ctx.channel());
    ctx.close();
}

}
```

ChatClient.java

```
package main;

import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ClassResolvers;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectEncoder;

public class ChatClient implements Runnable{
private final String host;
private final int port;

public ChatClient(String host, int port){
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
         .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(
                         new ObjectEncoder(),
                         new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.cacheDisabled(null)),
                         new ChatClientHandler());
             }
         });
        b.connect(host, port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ChatClient("localhost", 3000).run();
}

}
```

ChatClientHandler.java:

```
package main;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import net.Packet;
import net.client.ClientPacketHandler;
import net.client.PacketLoginCredentials;

public class ChatClientHandler extends ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<Packet>{
 private static final Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(ChatClientHandler.class.getName());

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Channel Active with with ChannelID: "+ctx.channel().id());
    ctx.write(new PacketLoginCredentials("martin", "123456"));
}

@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet p) throws Exception{
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "messageReceived with ClassEntity: "+p.getClass().getName());
    ClientPacketHandler.packetReceived(p, ctx.channel());
}
}
```

I have also already tried to telnet the server. The connection is established and closed immediately. I would guess its a server problem.

I am looking for the mistake for 2 days and just cant find it.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried printing something to `System.out` when `ChatServer.channelActive` is invoked, to at least let you know it's getting there, before you do `ctx.write`?  I suspect it's getting in there, and then failing on the `ctx.write` call and auto-closing the channel.

Comment: I just tried to add a sysout before the `ctx.write`. The ctx.write method is called, i also see this in debugger. I also see the output of the logger after `ctx.write` something like `INFO: Sent greetings packet to User with ChannelID: -1419778283`

Comment: Do you see anything on the chat client side?  You should see the message printed in the `messageReceived` method if you actually got the response from the server.  You should also put some output before the `group.shutdownGracefully();` in that finally block, see if you are getting there and it's closing the channel.  Also, what are you doing in `ClientPacketHandler.packetReceived`?  Are you inadvertently closing the channel?

Comment: i am currently out of range of running the project but the client does not call the messageReceived method or at least i do not receive any log that should be logged. In ClientPacketHandler I just call the internal handle method of a packet.

Comment: I just tested another point. The server somehow closes the connection. If I try to connect with Windows-Telnet the server is calling channelActive method and trying to send something (i know from debugger) but then almost immediately calling channelUnregistered method. i dont have any output in Windows-Telnet, so I guess it is a server problem